# Listings Package Line Number Bug?

Tags: listings

Dear TeX Wizs: The LaTeX

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}

%%
%% Julia definition (c) 2014 Jubobs
%%

\lstdefinelanguage{Julia}%
  {morekeywords={abstract,begin,break,case,catch,const,continue,do,else,elseif,%
      end,export,false,for,function,immutable,import,importall,if,in,%
      macro,module,otherwise,quote,return,switch,true,try,type,typealias,%
      using,while},%
   sensitive=true,%
   alsoother={$},%
   morecomment=[l]\#,%
   morecomment=[n]{\#=}{=\#},%
   morestring=[s]{"}{"},%
   morestring=[m]{'}{'},%
}[keywords,comments,strings]%

\lstset{%
    language         = Julia,
    basicstyle       = \ttfamily\scriptsize,
    numbers          = left,
    stepnumber       = 1,
    tabsize          = 4,
    formfeed         = \newpage,
    keywordstyle     = \bfseries\color{blue},
    stringstyle      = \color{magenta},
    commentstyle     = \color{ForestGreen},
    showstringspaces = false
}

\begin{document}

\section{Remove This SECTION Line To Reinvigorate Your Line Numbers}

\lstinputlisting{test.jl}

\end{document}
```

and the (julia) source code

```
"""

I love line numbers

"""

"""

where have my numbers gone?

"""
```

When typeset, the numbers disappear on page 2.  Removing the `\section` reinstates them on the second page.  Is this a known bug?

Comment: What page 2? If I add dummy text so the listing is split across two pages, I get numbers as expected.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. Weirdly, the line numbers will appear if you apply a frame. Try including `frame=single, framerule=0pt` as a workaround.

Comment: Or you can try `formfeed=\pagebreak`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either. With and without `\section` I get *one* page with line numbers for the listing in *both* cases. Version of `listings` is 2015-06-04 1.6. Compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `listings.sty 2015/06/04 1.6` and all engines.

Comment: yes, mine was weirdly intermittent, too.  at times, the problem appeared not on the first, but on the fifth listing.  for a given document, it would alway reappear on the same spot, but inncocuous document changes would change whether/where this showed up.  maybe it's an old version problem?  will try to update to latest texlive and packages.

Comment: To those that having difficulty reproducing this note that the file `test.jl` contains a form feed character